# how to prevent users from listing folders they do not have access to on windows 2012 RDS

Tags: security, filesystems, windows-server-2012

I have configured windows 2012 RDS and grant access to differnt users access remotely.
I need to find a ways of preventing users from viewing that some folders exisits when they are not allowed to access them.

Any help?

Answer (score 3):

[What you need is Access Based Enumeration](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc784710%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).  ABE is a method of only showing a user the folders they have access rights to.  If the user is not allowed in, they don't even know it exists.

[This link talks you through setting up ABE](http://tekrecipes.com/2014/03/02/access-based-enumeration-windows-server-2012-r2/) - but essentially, it is a case of opening server manager, loading "File and storage services", selecting the properties of a share, and turning on ABE within the share properties menu.

Comment: Niiiice. I like this as it makes an environment very clean. Users know what they can and can't access.

Comment: If you work in a college like i used to, its an absolute blessing!

Comment: Thanks,Can we do this for the drive c:\?

Comment: I see no real reason why not.

Comment: I work for a University and we have no end of staff wondering why they can't access a shared folder that their colleagues can access... it would be so nice if they simply couldn't see what they couldn't access!

Comment: Thats teh exact reason why we implemented it.  Staff used to get offended that they were denied access to things that didn't concern them

Comment: @Fazer87: ...and that phenomenon is not limited to college environments. :-)

Comment: i shared drive C for everyone with ABE on.

Comment: then i added a test folder and removed access for a specific user. the suer can still see this folder